# How to get EditText values from current Fragment in ViewPager to Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I have three tabs using `ViewPager`. How can I get `EditText` value from current `ViewPager` `Fragment` when I click on ActionBar button. When I click on ActionBar icon I want current `ViewPager` `EditText` values.

[My Example Code Is heare](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to get the `EditText` values in `Activity` and not the `Fragment`s?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the values in `Activity`, you can process the `EditText` values in the `Fragment` itself. Add the actionbar button in `onCreateOptionsMenu` in `Fragment` and then handle it in `onOptionsItemSelected` of the `Fragment`.

Comment: Tq @ replay...im created "onCreateOptionsMenu" and "onOptionsItemSelected" but how can i get current pager edit text value when im click actionbar button icon..

Comment: Where have you created these methods, in Activity or in Fragment?

Comment: I am suggesting to create the methods in Fragment. There you can easily get the values from EditText.

Comment: brother i dnt know how to get actionbar in fragment bar help me

Comment: You can use getActivity().getActionBar() to get the actionbar in Fragment